# How to get the data after : in python when it is transpilled to javascript, if and only if their syntax are matching to a greater extent?

Tags: javascript, python, replace

I have been making a python interpreter in javascript that can transpile similar looking python scripts to javascript ( I am making this because, I most of the time write simple python code that can be easily converted to javascript code with little syntax changes. So, I thought to write a function in javascript which can do that for me, by excepting the python code as text and outputting pure & valid javascript ). I have completed most of the work in my interpreter, but I am not able to solve this problem :

Converting :

```
if 3 > 2:
   # Do anything...
```

To :

```
if (3 > 2) {
   // Do anything...
}
```

So, far I went developing this part of the interpreter :

```
const py2js = (val) => {
   val = val.replace(/\b(if|for|while)\b([\S\s]*?)\:/gm, function(_, a, b) {
     return a + "(" + b + ") {"; // What to do here and in the above regex to catch the data after :
   }
}
```

I just progressed up-to this ! I am not understanding how to get the data after **:** So, can you help me complete my py2js ?

Comment: This seems especially tricky, since a colon at the end of a line in Python does not necessarily indicate the end of an if/for/while header. For example, `if {1: <newline> <tab> 2}: <newline> <tab> print("Hello")` is legal syntax, but it would be nonsense to translate it into `if ({1) { 2}: print("Hello"); }`

Comment: You may find Python's [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html) module useful here. `ast.parse` takes a string representing a Python program, and returns a tree-like data structure that represents the program in easily distinguishable nodes. For example, `ast.parse("if 3>2: print('ok')")` gives an `If` node which has a `test` attribute and a `body` attribute, which contain the nodes representing `3>2` and `print('ok')` respectively. No regex required.